# Why does my screen start at the centre of the scroll view? IOS

Tags: ios, swift

I have a large title navigation bar set up like this

```
private func navigationSetUp(){
    navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
    title = "Dashboard"
}
```

My problem is whenever I start the app it doesn't start the screen on the top of the page. However, when I scroll it works perfectly fine. I am using auto layout but I doubt it has anything to do with it.

[image]

Comment: in viewdidload add .        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        self.yourScrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = UIScrollView.ContentInsetAdjustmentBehavior.never
        } else {
            self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
        }

Comment: @Gagan_iOS didnt seem to work it just kind of made the scrollview unscrollable all the way to the top

Comment: You're not giving enough information. Is that thing a scroll view? Are all those elements inside it? If so, what makes the scroll view scrollable? (It shouldn't be, since it doesn't contain enough material to need scrolling.) If not, are those things pinned to the Safe Area?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my problem that no else would've possibly solved because lack of information in my question.

But I had the scrollviews setting up in the

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()


}
```

instead of adding it here

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

}
```

Answer (score -1):

I have added the same code which you write but for me this is coming perfectly fine did you check your constraints? If yes kindly reverify cause I think its due to your constraints.Check the attach image below:
[image: picture 1]

After scrolling, you can see it is coming fine:
[image: Picture 2]
Thanks, hope this will help you.